# Initializing class | Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

If I create in two separate Views reference to the class, do `order` and `myOrder` (in example above) are referencing to the same instance of a class, or they are references to different instances of a class (i.e. creating new instances of a class)?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var order = Order()
    ....
}

struct CheckoutView: View {
    // instead of @ObservedObject var order: Order
    @ObservedObject var myOrder = Order()
    .....
}
```

Class

```
class Order: ObservableObject {
    ....
    @Published var item = Item()
    ....
    ....
    init() { }
}
```

Comment: *or they are references to different instances of a class* - yes they are.

Answer (score 2):

They are creating new instances. If you'd like to share the same Object I guess you could do something like this:

Creating a state object in the first view and pass it to the second view as observed object. Or you could inject it as environment object.

View one with view model and model:

```
struct ContentView1: View {
    @StateObject var contentView1Model = ContentView1Model()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                TextField("ModelName", text: $contentView1Model.model.name)
                NavigationLink(destination: ContentView2(contentView2Model: contentView1Model)){
                    Text("ToContentView2")
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("ContentView1")
            }
        }
    }
}

class ContentView1Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var model = Model()
}

struct Model {
    var text = ""
}
```

View two:

```
struct ContentView2: View {
    @ObservedObject var contentView2Model: ContentView1Model
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                TextField("ModelName", text: $contentView2Model.model.name)
                    .navigationBarTitle("ContentView2")
        }
    }
}
```